# Checkbox is not editable org.jdesktop.beansbinding in jtable column

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, jtable

Need to edit the using Jcheckbox. I am using JTablebinding to populate data.
The expected behavior is to take the inputs from the checkbox and update the original list.
I have tried adding both CellEditor and Cellrenderer but the checkbox is not editable.
Below is the sample application I wrote. Please help.

[image: Sample UI]

```
public class MyDialog extends JFrame
{
  private JTable table = new JTable();

  public MyDialog() throws HeadlessException
  {
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

    //add the table to the frame
    this.add(scrollPane);

    this.setTitle("Table Example");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);

    initDataBindings();
    postBindings();
  }

  private void initDataBindings()
  {

    // create the peopel List
    List<DataWrapper> people = new ArrayList<>();
    people.add(new DataWrapper(true, "John"));
    people.add(new DataWrapper(false, "Rambo"));

    // create the binding from List to JTable
    JTableBinding tb = SwingBindings.createJTableBinding(AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, people, table);

    // define the properties to be used for the columns
    ObjectProperty<DataWrapper> selected = ObjectProperty.create();
    BeanProperty name = BeanProperty.create("name");

    // configure how the properties map to columns
    tb.addColumnBinding(selected).setColumnName("Selected");
    tb.addColumnBinding(name).setColumnName("Last Name");

    // realize the binding
    tb.bind();

  }

  private void postBindings()
  {
    table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

    final TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
    TableColumn column0 = columnModel.getColumn(0);
    
    column0.setCellRenderer(new DefaultTableCellRenderer()
    {
      JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox();

      @Override
      public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable jTable, Object o, boolean b, boolean b1, int i, int i1)
      {
        if (o != null)
        {
          DataWrapper dataWrapper = (DataWrapper) o;

          checkBox.setSelected(dataWrapper.isSelected());

          return checkBox;
        }

        return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(jTable, o, b, b1, i, i1);
      }
    });
  }
}

public class DataWrapper
{

  private final String name;

  private boolean selected;

  public DataWrapper(boolean selected, String name)
  {
    this.selected = selected;
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName()
  {
    return name;
  }

  public boolean isSelected()
  {
    return selected;
  }
}
```

Comment: I know nothing about the 3rd party classes you are using. I see no need to use them. The base JDK classes will do the job. The only change is that you may want to create a custom TableModel for your "DataWrapper" class. This will allow you to specify the "column class" of each column and allow the table to use the appropriate render/editor without creating a custom renderer/editor. Check out: [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for a step by step example on creating a custom model for your custom object.

Comment: Are you locked into [JFormDesigner](https://www.formdev.com/) or can you consider a solution that uses only classes from the JDK without any third-party libraries?